# HTML.Editor with null values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the folloiwng _CreateOrEdit partial view:-

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.RackJoin
@* This partial view defines form fields that will appear when creating and editing entities *@
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div >
    <span class="f">RU </span>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rack.RU)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rack.RU)
</div>



<div >
    <span class="f">Rack Name </span>
    @Html.Editor("assetName", (Model.Resource.RESOURCENAME == null ? String.Empty : Model.Resource.RESOURCENAME))

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Resource.RESOURCENAME)
</div>

<div >
```

the view will work well when editing an exsiting record, but if it is a new object i will get the following exception:-

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

on the following code inside the view:-

```
@Html.Editor("assetName", (Model.Resource.RESOURCENAME == null ? String.Empty : Model.Resource.RESOURCENAME))
```

***UPDATE***

The ACTION METHOD THAT CALLS THE ABOVE VIEW IS :-

```
  public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.PossibleDataCenters = repository.AllDataCenter().OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList() ;
            ViewBag.PossibleZones = repository.AllZone().OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
            ViewBag.Products = repository.GetProducts("Rack").OrderBy(a => a.COMPONENTNAME).ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: can u explain ur point ?

Comment: and what is the fix,, i mean were you able to fix it ?

Comment: Are you using hashset in database?

Comment: no i am not using hashset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is that when you are trying to pass in a new object then either you are passing in null model to the View or all the propertiese of the model are not initialized

so in the line

```
Model.Resource.RESOURCENAME
```

if either Model is null OR Model.Resource is null it will give the same error you are getting.

Try checking for NULL before using your `Model`

Comment: how i can do so ? I have provided the Get action method that calls this view.